# Strange issue in SSRS 2016. I am unable to select parameters or run the report intermittently, it works fine most of the time

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, ssrs-2016, power-bi-report-server

I am having a strange issue with SSRS 2016. We setup a new server and uploaded some reports, the reports ran fine for few days. The issue is, randomly the report doesnt run, When I load the report page, the parameters appear blank and I am unable to select any parameters[image: error screenshot]. If I try to run and click the view reports button, nothing happens. After few mins/hours, it automatically resolves.

We have contacted MS support and could not get anything to get this resolved

Has Anybody faced a similar issue ?

Answer (score 0):

This does not constitute an answer but it won't fit in a comment!

Does this affect more than one report?

If more than one, do they all fail at the same time or will one work and another not when you try to run the at the same time?

If the situation is "all fail" or "all work" at any single point in time then try adding a new report with no parameters.

If this attempts to run when other reports fail then it sounds like the datasource cannot be resolved or a timeout connecting to the database.

If your parameters are populated by querying the database the report will 'hang' until it can complete the queries to populate the parameters so by running a parameter-less report you should see an error instead.

Try running a trace on the database server to see if you can see the queries being run at all.

A bit vague I know but it might help you understand where the problem lies a little better.

Comment: This affects all reports, even if the report does not have parameters it does not run. I ran a trace on the database and it does not hit that point.

Also, an inspection of the network calls from my browser reveals that at times when it fails there are some ScriptResources.axd calls failing. I believe these calls have the js required to load parameters and run the report. Why its failing randomly is something i don't understand